# Detect when two keys are pressed on the same time

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

I want to do something when two keys are pressed at the same time.

This is not working for me.
Don't know why.

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F12) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1))
{
  MessageBoxA(0, "Injection is working!", "Succes!", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);
}
```

I want to know how to achieve so that code is executed when I press two keys at the same time.

Comment: You didn't ask an actual question.  Don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know your code is getting called at the time the keys are getting pressed?

For your code to be getting called your in ether:

- in the message pump, in which case handle the [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646281%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) events, and check if the keys are "down" at the same time.
- in a timer thread, not sure the best way here.

Comment: When I use only one key it works. But I don't know how to do it with more than one.

Comment: Is that if you check only one key, but press both it works? or press one and check one?

Answer (score 0):

Many keyboards are unable to detect multiple keys pressed at once. Check different combination.